# Magento 1.9.2 Custom Attribute Not Working

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.9

I have searched everywhere and cannot find an answer for some reason. I have had my first attribute save and work in my database, but my second attribute will not work. I believe that my installer script is not being executed, which is incredibly frustrating.  Here is what I have:

```
app/local/Name/Module/sql/name_module_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
```

(please note that I have had this same script in `.../mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` and `.../mysql4-install-0.1.1.php` in order to try different things)

```
    <?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
//$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup; //this line has been both commented and non-commented

$attribute  = array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'backend_type'  => 'text',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'is_user_defined' => false,
    'label'         => 'Custom ID',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'searchable'    => true,
    'filterable'    => true,
    'comparable'    => true,
    'default'       => 'Test'
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_id', $attribute);

$attribute  = array(
    'type'          => 'int',
    'backend_type'  => 'int',
    'frontend_input' => 'int',
    'is_user_defined' => false,
    'label'         => 'Custom Number',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'searchable'    => true,
    'filterable'    => true,
    'comparable'    => true,
    'default'       => '0'
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_number', $attribute);

error_log("The new custom number attribute is being made",0); //Never sent to error_log
$installer->endSetup();
```

...app/local/Name/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Name_Module>
            <version>0.1.1</version><!--Tried 0.1.0 and 0.1.1-->
        </Name_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <name_module>
                <class>Name_Module_Model</class>
            </name_module>
        </models>
        ...
        <resources>
            <name_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Name_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </name_module_setup>
            <module_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </module_write>
            <module_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </module_read>
        </resources>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <custom_id>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </custom_id>
                <custom_number>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </custom_number>
            </sales_convert_quote>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

I feel like I have tried everything... Any help would be fantastic! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Swapna,

Please turn on display error using the code `ini_set('display_errors',0);`
, execute the code and share the error message.

Thanks,
Shivanand.

Comment: Hey Shivanand... I implemented this part of the code, but nothing happened because I believe that the installer is not being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out finally... for some reason, I had to go into **phpmyadmin** and go to `core/resource` and delete the rows that contain your module, refresh cache, and try again.  After that, the installer script ran! Hope this helps somebody out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('order', 'custom_id', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'backend_type'  => 'text',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'is_user_defined' => false,
    'label'         => 'Custom ID',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'searchable'    => true,
    'filterable'    => true,
    'comparable'    => true,
    'default'       => 'Test'

));

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('order', 'custom_number', array(
    'type'          => 'int',
    'backend_type'  => 'int',
    'frontend_input' => 'int',
    'is_user_defined' => false,
    'label'         => 'Custom Number',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'searchable'    => true,
    'filterable'    => true,
    'comparable'    => true,
    'default'       => '0'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Try to clear magento cache and check.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, it did not work. I don't think that the installer is being executed at all